# SQL - How to combine the results from a UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

UPDATE:

As requested, Here is the 'real' SQL:

```
    SELECT      p.ReferenceNumber, 
            p.Name, 
            '' as 'Size of Prize',
            '' as 'Complexity', 
            pfc.ConfigurationValue as 'Strategic Fit'
FROM        FormConfigurations AS fc INNER JOIN
                      ProjectForms AS pf ON pf.FormID = fc.FormID INNER JOIN
                      ProjectFormConfigurations AS pfc ON pfc.ProjectFormID = pf.ID AND pfc.FormConfigurationID = fc.ID INNER JOIN
                      Project AS p ON p.ID = pf.ProjectID
WHERE     (fc.[Key] = 'Strategic Fit') 
GROUP BY p.ReferenceNumber, p.Name, pfc.ConfigurationValue, fc.[Key]

UNION

SELECT      p.ReferenceNumber, 
            p.Name, 
            '' as 'Size of Prize',
            pfc.ConfigurationValue as 'Complexity', 
            '' 'Strategic Fit'
            FROM         FormConfigurations AS fc INNER JOIN
                      ProjectForms AS pf ON pf.FormID = fc.FormID INNER JOIN
                      ProjectFormConfigurations AS pfc ON pfc.ProjectFormID = pf.ID AND pfc.FormConfigurationID = fc.ID INNER JOIN
                      Project AS p ON p.ID = pf.ProjectID
WHERE     (fc.[Key] = 'Complexity') 
GROUP BY p.ReferenceNumber, p.Name, pfc.ConfigurationValue, fc.[Key]

UNION

SELECT      p.ReferenceNumber, 
            p.Name, 
    pfc.ConfigurationValue  as 'Size of Prize',
    '' as 'Complexity',
    '' as 'Strategic Fit'
    FROM         FormConfigurations AS fc INNER JOIN
                      ProjectForms AS pf ON pf.FormID = fc.FormID INNER JOIN
                      ProjectFormConfigurations AS pfc ON pfc.ProjectFormID = pf.ID AND pfc.FormConfigurationID = fc.ID INNER JOIN
                      Project AS p ON p.ID = pf.ProjectID
WHERE     (fc.[Key] = 'Projected EBIT') 
GROUP BY p.ReferenceNumber, p.Name, pfc.ConfigurationValue, fc.[Key]
```

I have a table which has a KeyValue column which acts as a placeholder for columns not known at design time which is necessary for another piece of large software. I need to get the records based on certain values from the KeyValue column; in this case, let's call the desired values Foo, Bar, and Baz. Each record retrieved must have all three values, or else they shouldn't display at all.

Here's the query I tried using unions:

```
SELECT  KeyValue as 'Foo',
        '' as 'Bar', 
        '' as 'Baz' 
FROM        Table1
WHERE     KeyValue = 'Foo' 
UNION
SELECT  '' as 'Foo',
        KeyValue as 'Bar',
        '' as 'Baz'
FROM        Table1
WHERE     KeyValue = 'Bar' 
SELECT  '' as 'Foo',
        '' as 'Bar', 
        KeyValue as  'Baz'
FROM        Table1
WHERE     KeyValue = 'Baz'
```

Unfortunately, what happens is that I have jagged records instead of the one record with all the columns filled up. That is, instead of me getting the desired records like the ones below:

```
Foo     Bar     Baz
 -       -       -
 -       -       -
 -       -       -
 -       -       -
 -       -       -
```

I am getting these instead:

```
Foo     Bar     Baz
 -              
         -       
                 -
 -              
         -       
                 -
```

What do I need to do to correct my query?

Comment: I think you need to JOIN the tables.

Comment: That's indeed a JOIN and not a UNION

Comment: Use double quotes for column aliases, e.g. `"Foo"`. Single quotes are for string literals.

Comment: what do you expect in other 2 columns ? is it NULL ?

Comment: Give us some real data expectations. In ur case isn't it normal to get the 2nd result??

Comment: Does my answer resolve your problem ?

Comment: @JahangirAlam unforunately, no. What happened is that they still show up in the same jagged like records

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.KeyValue as 'Foo', t2.KeyValue as 'Bar', t3.KeyValue as 'Baz',
from Table1 t1, Table1 t2, Table1 t3
where t1.KeyValue = 'Foo' and t2.KeyValue = 'Bar' and t3.KeyValue = 'Baz'
```

Comment: I know, but he didn't give us any data on which we could offer him a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is select subqueries instead of union. A union will combine multiple row-sources into 1 row source, but what you need is that for a single row, you want to fetch values from multiple tables.

Example:

```
select *, 
  (select KeyValue from table1 where somekey = outertable.somekey) as Foo
from outertable where somerestrictions
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement then there are many ways to get records as you mentioned and one of the simple way is:

```
SELECT  KeyValue as 'Foo',
        (SELECT  KeyValue FROM zzz WHERE KeyValue = 'Bar') as 'Bar', 
        (SELECT  KeyValue FROM zzz WHERE KeyValue = 'Baz') as 'Baz'
FROM table1
WHERE KeyValue = 'Foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you did not put a 'union' before third select query.

If you want to eliminate duplicate rows you should use 'UNION ALL' as like as follows:

```js
SELECT  KeyValue as 'Foo',
        '' as 'Bar', 
        '' as 'Baz' 
FROM        Table1
WHERE     KeyValue = 'Foo' 
UNION All
SELECT  '' as 'Foo',
        KeyValue as 'Bar',
        '' as 'Baz'
FROM        Table1
WHERE     KeyValue = 'Bar' 
UNION All
SELECT  '' as 'Foo',
        '' as 'Bar', 
        KeyValue as  'Baz'
FROM        Table1
WHERE     KeyValue = 'Baz'
```

And if you don't want to eliminate duplicate then you should use only 'UNION' as like as follows:

```js
SELECT  KeyValue as 'Foo',
        '' as 'Bar', 
        '' as 'Baz' 
FROM        Table1
WHERE     KeyValue = 'Foo' 
UNION
SELECT  '' as 'Foo',
        KeyValue as 'Bar',
        '' as 'Baz'
FROM        Table1
WHERE     KeyValue = 'Bar' 
UNION
SELECT  '' as 'Foo',
        '' as 'Bar', 
        KeyValue as  'Baz'
FROM        Table1
WHERE     KeyValue = 'Baz'
```

I think that should resolve your problem. 
If you want you can see the difference between 'UNION' and 'UNION ALL'.

Thank you